# maven antrun plugin

Tags: ant, maven-2, maven-antrun-plugin

I have the following in my pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ant-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
       <target>
          <echo
            message="hello ant, from Maven!" />
          <echo>Maybe this will work?</echo>
       </target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Yet, when I run 'mvn antrun:run' I get this:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'antrun'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myProject
[INFO]    task-segment: [antrun:run]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [antrun:run {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Executing tasks
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Sep 24 13:33:14 PDT 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/28M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How come the echo's don't show up?

TIA

Comment: To reiterate something I missed - make sure and use version 1.5+ of the plugin.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because you are supposed to use the [Maven AntRun Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) if you want to execute Ant tasks, not the [Maven Ant Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ant-plugin/) (which is used to *generate build files for Ant 1.6.2 or above from the POM*). Modify your plugin configuration as below:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <configuration>
      <target>
        <echo message="hello ant, from Maven!"/>
        <echo>Maybe this will work?</echo>
      </target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

And invoking `antrun:run` will work:

```
$ mvn antrun:run 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Q3790798 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.5:run (default-cli) @ Q3790798 ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [echo] hello ant, from Maven!
     [echo] Maybe this will work?
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

Comment: Oh man, what a ludicrously simple yet irritating bug! Thanks so much, you're like the Jon Skeet for Java :D

Comment: @javamonkey79 You're welcome. Confusion between both plugins happens, it's the mismatch between the versions that got my attention.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure `maven-antrun-plugin` is using a recent enough version.

An unrelated BOM in my project was locking it to 1.3, and `<echo>` was being ignored. After removing the BOM and specifying **1.7** for antrun, the echoes worked.